# how to pass a rpm spec parameter to C++ program

Tags: c++, cmake, rpm

let's assume that we have a rpm .spec file with following parameter:

```
Version:       0.1.0
```

I want to pass this parameter to C++ code from the same package, i.e. I would like to initialize with this value a C++ variable:

```
const std::string program_version([here goes 0.1.0 read from the .spec file]);
```

I am using cmake and I suppose that first step would be (in .spec file):

```
%cmake . -DVERSION=%{version}
```

Any hints? Thank you in advance ;>

Comment: if you already have the `VERSION` preprocessor definition can't you just do `#VERSION` like described here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

Comment: I did it in following steps: 1) [in .spec file]: %cmake . -DVERSION=%{version} 2) [in CMakeLists.txt]: ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DVERSION="${VERSION}") 3) [in C++]: const std::string program_version = std::string(VERSION);