# how to pass values from an rpm .spec file to a python script?

Tags: python, rpm, specifications

I have a following question, which btw. is very similar to the question I already asked:

[how to pass a rpm spec parameter to C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357708/how-to-pass-a-rpm-spec-parameter-to-c-program)

This time I would like to use value in Python script, which is defined in RPM .spec file. 
Particularly I would like to know if there is a way to read value of _datadir in Python?

Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RPM Python interface (documented at [RPM API](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/group__python.html)).

For example:

```
import os, rpm

def get_rpm_version(path):

    # open .rpm file
    fdno = os.open(path, os.O_RDONLY)

    # init transaction set
    ts = rpm.TransactionSet()

    # read header
    hdr = ts.hdrFromFdno(fdno)

    # close file
    os.close(fdno)

    # return version
    return hdr['version']
```